# knitr with latex forloop

Tags: r, for-loop, latex, knitr

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but does anyone know how to loop over R functions in knitr? My problem thus far is passing the variable from latex to the R function. I am trying to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{ind}  
\begin{document}

%Simple R function:
<<simpleRFun, results='asis' ,echo=FALSE>>=
simpleRFun = function(ind){
  set.seed(ind) ;
  plot(runif(100)) ;
}
@

%Run the function for value of 1
<<>>=
simpleRFun(1)
@

%Run the function for value of 2
<<>>=
simpleRFun(2)
@

%Loop over values of 1 and 2:
\forloop{ind}{1}{\value{ind} < 3}{
   \arabic{ind}
}

%Loop over values of 1 and 2 and pass to R function:
%Everything runs fine until this line:
\forloop{ind}{1}{\value{ind} < 3}{
<<>>=
simpleRFun(ind)
@
}

\end{document}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
 #### Error: object 'ind' not found \end {verbatim} \end {kframe} \end \ETC.
./knitr-minimal.tex:97: Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.97 }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: why do you use `results='asis'` for the first chunk? that does not make sense because that chunk does not have any text output; what is more, you have also hidden the R source by `echo=FALSE`, so basically nothing will be written into tex

Comment: if all else fails, you can probably do it with `brew`, and output a  knit-able file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can do what you are trying to do (at least not in the way that you are trying to do it).  The `knitr` function runs all the R code without doing anything with the LaTeX code, then you use LaTeX on the results and it does not run R for the R part.

Can you redo your loop to do the looping in R so that `knitr` puts the results of the loop into the LaTeX?

Either that or you need an extension to LaTeX that will run the R part for you.

Comment: Greg, thanks for the feedback. But I am pretty sure that it will work this way, and there are advantages if it does- namely that I can insert latex at very level of the loop. The code
    %Everything runs fine until this line:
    \forloop{ind}{1}{\value{ind} < 3}{
    <<>>=
    simpleRFun(1)
    @
    }
runs the R code fine (twice), just for the same variable (here, for a value of 1). I just need to get the variable from the loop to pass to the R. I believe that the problem is my lack of understanding on my part of how to pass environment variables in latex. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you really sure that R runs that section twice?  Do you have a variable called `ind` in your R workspace? (if so remove it and try again, you might get an error instead).  What I think is happening above is that `knitr` runs `SimpleRfun(ind)` once in R ignoring the LaTeX for loop and using the local to R copy of ind, then LaTeX takes that output and includes it twice.  `knitr` ignores (and passes on) all the LaTeX code (including the loop) and just replaces the R code with its outpu, then LaTeX processes the file with only output, no code remaining.

Comment: Ahh, I believe that you are right. I just added 'ind' to the graph (main= ind) and it is, as you say, just replicating the graph twice. Do you know, instead, of any way of adding direct latex to the loop inside my R chunk? I need the latex to update at every interval of the loop. Thanks.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you really want to do here; if you want to produce two plots in a loop, why not `for (i in 1:2) simpleRFun(i)`? If you want to write native TeX output from R chunks, you can use chunk option `results='asis'` combined with some `cat()` statements in R code.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, that does the trick. I have had some trouble controlling the output of loops in the R chunks, the order of plots seems to get all jumbled. But with some function calling I think that I have it sorted out. By the way- do you know why cat() renders TeX? I had tried using print() and paste().

Comment: @JimCrozier The `paste` function just combines strings together but does not print them (but if you don't assign the results then print is called on the results).  The `print` function is used to "pretty print" or format output and sometimes only shows a subset of the object being "printed" and can add additional information.  The `cat` function pastes its arguments together then dumps them as is to the screen or file (the name `cat` comes from the common misuse of the unix cat command that was originally short for concatenate).